# Tell the linker to avoid a region

Tags: linker, ld, linker-scripts

Esteemed Colleagues!

If I want the linker to not place anything into an area of memory, I can simply omit the region from the "MEMORY" section in the linker script file.  I could also put a comment in there to make it clear what I'm doing.  Perhaps like this:

```
MEMORY
{
  ...
  good_one   : ORIGIN = 0x00400000, LENGTH = 0x00010000  /* 64 kiB */
  /* Avoid the "special" area 0x00410000 -> 0x00480000 */
  good_two   : ORIGIN = 0x00480000, LENGTH = 0x00010000  /* 64 kiB */
  ...
}
```

Instead, is there a way that I could define a memory region, but attach attributes to it to keep the linker from placing anything in there?  Perhaps like this:

```
MEMORY
{
  ...
  good_one          : ORIGIN = 0x00400000, LENGTH = 0x00010000  /*  64 kiB */
  avoid    (!rwiax) : ORIGIN = 0x00410000, LENGTH = 0x00070000  /* 448 kiB */
  good_two          : ORIGIN = 0x00480000, LENGTH = 0x00010000  /*  64 kiB */
  ...
}
```

Could I also create some symbols (and "KEEP" them) in the linker script file that would show up in the ELF to clearly indicate what is going on?  Perhaps like this:

```
SECTIONS
{
  ...
  avoid 0x00410000 (NOLOAD) :
  {
    _avoid_region_start = .  ;  /* KEEP() ??? */
    . = . + 0x00070000       ;
    _avoid_region_end = .    ;  /* KEEP() ??? */
  } > avoid                  ;
  ...
```

I'm using a wide variety of GNU "ld" versions (from 2.20.51 through 2.36.1), cross-compiling to a broad set of target architectures (riscv32/64, aarch32/64, etc...), if that matters...